# Getting error could not resolve hostname for github enterprise

Tags: github, windows-10, hostname, github-enterprise

When I trying to `clone github repositories` from my company's self hosted github enterprise

I am getting error

`Could not resolve hostname github....... : Name or service not known`

But when I clone the same repo using the IP address I can do the same and I am even able to ping the `github.....` from command line.

I am using :

```
GIT version : git version 2.14.1.windows.1
Windows 10 enterprise version version: 1607 OS build: 14393
```

I have checked others with similar machine are not facing this issue

Can someone please help me with this issue.

Comment: Seems like a DNS problem caused by your company. Since your company probably hosting own DNS servers I guess that´s the best point to start. Otherwise: are you able to access the webadresses of the repos?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but others are able to use the github repo normally even from the windows 10, is there anyway I can create some certificate to be added in to my machine

Comment: You can´t create the certificate yourself (if that´s what you need). If your company runs an IT team/ network admin i guess that´s where you should go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, so while `installing Git` the 
`installer asks if I want to use the certificates installed on my Local Machine` 
to which earlier said no.

But after re-installing the Git, I selected this option and since that Github's certificate was installed on my machine by my company it was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a host entry on my windows machine that defines the github address to the IP address you need to use.

Here is one procedure that describes how it works.  Basically you edit the hosts file as administrator , it is located in an out of the way dir c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

(I havent done it myself for windows 10)

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/

Of course this may not be available option to you depending on your local Infosec policies/enforcement

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes, thats what I was doing currently, but I was looking for the reason for the problem why it was happening for me only.